# Android code works fine on Gingerbread but breaks on Nexus 7 w/ 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

I have 2 devices. Droid x3 w/ Gingerbread and a Nexus 7 w/ Jellybean 4.2.2.
I compile and run this code on my Droid x3 and it runs perfectly.
Yet the exact same code I run on the Nexus 7 and it breaks.

Code and Stack trace included.

Thanks for the help!

```
package com.jacobschellenbergflickrsearch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class DataDownloader {

    String apiKey = "bc370c6386192bf6e2f950cdfddfda48";
    //String url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=bc370c6386192bf6e2f950cdfddfda48&nojsoncallback=1&text=monkey&format=json&per_page=10";


    public String buildUrl(String searchMethod, String searchQuery, int perpage){

        String url = String.format("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=%s&api_key=%s&nojsoncallback=1&text=%s&format=json&per_page=%s", searchMethod, this.apiKey, searchQuery, perpage);

        String result = null;

        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s;

            while(true)
            {
                s = buf.readLine();
                if(s==null || s.length()==0){
                    break;
                }
                sb.append(s);
            }
            buf.close();
            ips.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "IllegalStateException";
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "IOException";
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "URISyntaxException";
        }

        return "Query: " + url + " : Result: " + result;
    }
}
```

> 05-01 13:47:04.742: D/AndroidRuntime(4526): Shutting down VM 05-01
>   13:47:04.742: W/dalvikvm(4526): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x41377930) 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not
>   execute method of the activity 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599) 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 05-01
>   13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 05-01
>   13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 05-01
>   13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 05-01
>   13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-01
>   13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 05-01
>   13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-01
>   13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594) 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   ... 11 more 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526): Caused by:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 05-01 13:47:04.752:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385) 05-01
>   13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236) 05-01
>   13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214) 05-01
>   13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   com.jacobschellenbergflickrsearch.DataDownloader.buildUrl(DataDownloader.java:31)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   at
>   com.jacobschellenbergflickrsearch.MainActivity.searchImage(MainActivity.java:47)
>   05-01 13:47:04.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4526):   ... 14 more 05-01
>   13:47:04.802: D/dalvikvm(4526): GC_CONCURRENT freed 210K, 5% free
>   7474K/7812K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 46ms

Answer (score 5):

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

You are doing network I/O on the main application thread. This is an exceptionally bad idea on any version of Android, and it raises an actual exception on Android 4.0+.

Please perform your network I/O on a background thread, such as by using an `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

That is your problem. Do not call network actions on the UI thread. You should not do that ever. Since ICS it is forbidden.

Use a AsyncTask and call the client.execute() inside doInBackground(). That will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you are doing a newtwork call on the main thread...you cannot do that, it must be in a seperate thread